# Follow-up code not executing after checking permissions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

The code I have written should check the permissions in the `OnStart` method and regardless of the outcome of whether the user gives access, the same two pieces of code should execute:

1. Starting my service
2. Auto-login the user if they have provided credentials before

If I retype my credentials and turn the app on and off then on again - then for around 2-5 minutes it will automatically log me in. If I have the app off for longer than that, the autologin will not work.

**OnStart:**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM);

    checkPermission(permissions.toArray(new String[0]), INITIAL_REQUESTS_CODE);
}
```

**checkPermission Function:**

```
  public void checkPermission(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    // Checking if permission is not granted
    boolean ungrantedPermissions = false;
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ungrantedPermissions = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ungrantedPermissions)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
    else{
        startStepCounterService();
        attemptLoginWithSavedCredentials();
    }
}
```

**onRequestPermissionResult:**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,
            permissions,
            grantResults);

    startStepCounterService();
    attemptLoginWithSavedCredentials();
}
```

**startStepCounterService Function:**

```
  private void startStepCounterService() {
    if(!isMyServiceRunning(StepCounterService.class))
    {
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, StepCounterService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(newIntent);
        } else {
            startService(newIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**attemptLoginWithSavedCredentials Function:**

```
    private void attemptLoginWithSavedCredentials() {
    String savedUsername = SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(this);
    String savedPassword = SaveSharedPreference.getUserPassword(this);
    if(!savedUsername.isEmpty() && !savedPassword.isEmpty())
    {
        LoadingExtensions.showLoadingIcon(loadingIndicator, rootView);
        loginManager.login(savedUsername, savedPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define clearly what issue you are facing? Is your onRequestPermissionResult callback is not being triggered or your Service is not started even after it is being triggered?

Comment: @nitinkumarp The autoLogin function above does not log me in despite having previously saved credentials. From my observation, the onRequestPermissionResult is not being triggered otherwise the user would have been logged in immediately after the callback to onRequestPermissionResult.